# SQL query that I can only get the first half of

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have a question regarding a query I am trying to create.  I want to create a query that will List members'name for who ever checked out one oe more books and have returned ALL of them.  I have a query (shown below that finds the entries if there Return Date is no NULL but I can't figure out how to now show the Names if they have a returned book but still have another book they have no returned (Return Date = NULL).  Below is my script if anybody can give me some advice.  Thank you.

```
SELECT  MemName
FROM MEMBER, CHECK_OUT
WHERE MEMBER.ID = CHECK_OUT.MemID
AND CHECK_OUT.DateRet IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think you'll want to do a join [See this as a good tutorial for it](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking, you want a query that will return all members who currently have a book checked out, correct?

Something like this might be what you want:

```
SELECT
    M.MemName
FROM
    MEMBER AS M
        INNER JOIN CHECK_OUT AS C ON (C.MemID = M.ID)
WHERE
    C.DateRet IS NULL
```

This will list all member names that have something checked out, but will not remove duplicates. To list each name only one, use `SELECT DISTINT`. To get the names who do NOT have anything checked out anymore (but did at one point) use either your query or modify mine to say `C.DateRet IS NOT NULL`. I personally just like using INNER JOINS in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a query that will List members' names for who ever checked out one or more books and have returned ALL of them.

```
SELECT MEMBER.MemName
FROM MEMBER, CHECK_OUT
WHERE MEMBER.ID = CHECK_OUT.MemID
group by MEMBER.ID, MEMBER.MemName
having max(nvl2(CHECK_OUT.DateRet, 0, 1)) = 0
```